# how to apply text styles in div with contenteditable attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, textstyle

How to apply text styles like bold, italicize, and underline in div with "contenteditable" attribute?

I used,

```
contenteditable="true"
```

attribute in my elements that I want to be editable. I would like to add an option to make it Bold, Italicized, or Underlined.

I research about this and only way I found is using some plugins. I prefer not to use other plugins.

Comment: Try applying css classes to your inputs. Each for bold, italic underline. Mix and match them using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `execCommand` .

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/nn9cm5n2/1/)

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Bold').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('bold');
  });
   $('#Italic').click(function() {
    document.execCommand('italic');
  });
});
```

[Full option's link for execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Almost all modern browser support it.